Tailwind not installed error when I run the first command in cmd
npm: File C: \Program Files\nodejs\pm.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. For more information, see about_ Execution Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1

pm install -D tailwindess + nun
CategoryInfo
: SecurityError: (:) [l, PSSecurityException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess

**# I installed Node.js, I installed NPM, and I even removed them and reinstalled them, and it still gave me this error, and I got tired of it, and it gave me this error again
